# SSHFS connects works with command but not fstab

Tags: fstab, sshfs

sshfs works when I connect with the command line:

```
jack@lap:~$ sshfs jack@192.168.0.10:/home/jack/LanDrive ~/LanDrive
```

But not when I try to mount it through fstab using this:

```
sshfs jack@192.168.0.10:/home/jack/Tabernash/040/home/jack/Tabernash fuse _netdev,delay_connect,allow_other,default_permissions,noauto,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa 0 0
```

or

```
jack@192.168.0.10:/home/jack/Tabernash/040/home/jack/Tabernash fuse default_permissions,noauto,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa 0 0
```

Then

```
$ sudo findmnt --verify --verbose
```

Returns this:

```
fuse
   [E] unreachable on boot required target: No such file or directory
   [ ] FS options: 0
   [W] unreachable source: jack@192.168.50.10:/home/jack/Tabernash/040/home/jack/Tabernash: No such file or directory
   [W] default_permissions,noauto,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa seems unsupported by the current kernel
   [W] cannot detect on-disk filesystem type
```

I've tried a lot of other variations in fstab, but it never works.

The client is a desktop running Ubuntu 20.04 and the server is a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu Server 20.10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *latest* isn't very helpful; most users only count the LTS releases which is **not** the latest at all..   you should be specific with releases.

Comment: Refer to prior comment; Ubuntu Cinnamon is a *re-spin* and not a *flavor* of Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you really have it as such in `/etc/fstab`? In both your versions the filesystem type should read `fuse.sshfs` instead of just `fuse` and the 040 between the remote directory and the local mount point should be a blank space (at least in Ubuntu). As far as the rest, the second listing should be the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at systemd mounts?

```
# /etc/systemd/system/media.mount (Naming is important)
[Unit]
Description=Mount remote /media with sshfs
Before=cron.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Mount]
What=ssh@home.local:/media/
Where=/media
Type=fuse.sshfs
Options=_netdev,allow_other,IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/ssh@home.mount,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=30,ServerAliveCountMax=5,x-systemd.automount,uid=1000,gid=1000
TimeoutSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: In had not, but I read about it after getting your suggestion.  I'm going to try it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I have the same problem, only my error in `sudo findmnt --verify --verbose` says `Input/output error` instead. I don't have `media.mount` under `/etc/systemd/system`. What could it mean and what could I be doing wrong?